# .htaccess url redirect with exception

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, staging

I have the following rule in my htaccess. It redirects the root URL and any unfound urls/files to my Wordpress installation (subfolder).

How can I create an exception rule so that if the URI begins with /staging/ the rule doesn't apply?

```
# REDIRECT TO THE WP FOLDER IF FILE REQUESTED DOESNT EXIST
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT]
RewriteRule (.*) /livesite/$1 [L]
```

Hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Exception rule would be `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/staging/`
Hope I got it correctly

```
# REDIRECT TO THE WP FOLDER IF FILE REQUESTED DOESNT EXIST
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/staging/
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT]
RewriteRule (.*) /livesite/$1 [L]
```